# How can I remove extra space from input form dropdown in BootStrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to make a input form dropdown  using bootstrap(BootStrap version 2.3.2), but my form dropwdown make a irrelevant space with it.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="control-group" >
      <label class="control-label">Event Name</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend">

        <? $result=$this->db->get("EventType")->result();
           foreach($result as $res){
             $event[$res->Id]=$res->Name;
           }
           $event["Select"]="Select";
           $js = 'id="events" class="input-large" onChange="some_function();"';
           echo form_dropdown("event_type",$event, 'Select',$js); ?>
        </div>
        <? echo '<span style=color:red>'.form_error('event_name').'</span>'; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Event Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend">
            <select name="event_type" id="events" class="width" onChange="some_function();">
                <option value="6">Music</option>
                <option value="7">Seminar</option>
                <option value="8">Sports</option>
                <option value="9">Movie</option>
                <option value="11">Conference</option>
                <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option>
            </select>
        </div> <span style=color:red></span>    
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my output image
[image]

There is a gap between button of a dropdown and input text(Right side gap of the text). How can I remove this gap?

But, I want to make this input form dropdown like as [image]
No extra space of right side.

Comment: It makes me curious on what made the button so tiny in the first place. Anyways, could you paste your rendered HTML?

Comment: Always a good idea to post the additional code back into the original question so that nobody misses it. `input-prepend` looks like Bootstrap 2.3 but that's not how it should look like. Do you have any custom CSS for the select box?

Comment: No.There is no css for select box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there is a style in your css for select or textarea.
Whatever, You can use this style for select.

```
  .select,
    textarea,
    input[type="text"]{
    padding:0px;
   }
```

I hope you will success.So,Try it.